# Filter data in datagridview using two datetimer pickers

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Am trying to filter data in a datagridview based on two dates and the account number selected through a combobox. I have three records in my access table one for 01/05/2017 another for 16/05/2017 and the other for 20/05/2017. When i select from 08/05/2017-20/05/2017 i don't get any data yet it should display the two records for 16/05/2017 and 20/05/2017. See my code below

```
    Dim StartDate As Date = dtpfrom.Value.Date
    Dim EndDate As Date = dtpto.Value.Date

    Try
        myconnection()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM tblbankposting WHERE AccountNo='" & cboaccounts.Text & "' AND BankEntryDate BETWEEN "
        sql &= "#" & StartDate & "# and #" & EndDate & "#"

        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
        dt = New DataTable("tblbankposting")
        adapter.Fill(dt)
        TblbankpostingDataGridView.DataSource = dt
        TblbankpostingDataGridView.Sort(TblbankpostingDataGridView.Columns(1), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "CMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code.  Use parameters and you avoid potential issues with date formats, which is likely to be the issue here.  You could start here to learn how to do that: http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: i did use parameters while inserting the data. So not sure the problem was with the inserting part

Comment: That's irrelevant to using parameters in your query.  ALWAYS use parameters when inserting values into SQL code.  While it can be OK not to if you do it properly, if you do it every time then you don't have to worry that you might not be doing it properly.